# Is the space after the differential d operator canonical when using a Times font?

Tags: math-mode, macros, symbols, mtpro, newtx

I have this simple code,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
$d\bar{p}$ and $dt$.
\end{document}
```

with this output,

[image]

I think it's a canonical space is due to the presence of the `\bar{...}` command? Sometimes to bring it back I insert a negative space `\!` to bring the `p` to the left near the `d`.

This little adjustment must always be done or I should create a particular macro. Which one could be always using the same command `\bar`? It gets a bit complicated for me in my book to change the original command `\bar{...}`. Thank you.

---

Using Steven Segletes' suggestion of `\ooalign{$d\bar{#1}$\cr$d#1$}`, one can see if the problem is universal across `\bar`.   If the superposition produces a "thick" second letter, the kerning is not correct.  (using `newtxmath` as Steven does not have `mtpro2`)

Unfortunately, that proves not to be the case, as some cases seem kerned correctly and others not:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}%instead of \usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\newcommand\testkern[1]{%
  \ooalign{$d\bar{#1}$\cr$d#1$}}
\textwidth 1in
\begin{document}
\noindent\testkern{a}
\testkern{b}
\testkern{c}
\testkern{d}
\testkern{e}
\testkern{f}
\testkern{g}
\testkern{h}
\testkern{i}
\testkern{j}
\testkern{k}
\testkern{l}
\testkern{m}
\testkern{n}
\testkern{o}
\testkern{p}
\testkern{q}
\testkern{r}
\testkern{s}
\testkern{t}
\testkern{u}
\testkern{v}
\testkern{w}
\testkern{x}
\testkern{y}
\testkern{z}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Applying a universal `-1mu` kern to `\bar`

```
\newcommand\xbar{\mkern-1mu\bar}
\newcommand\testkern[1]{%
  \ooalign{$d\xbar{#1}$\cr$d#1$}}
```

therefore, may fix some letter combinations, but will inevitably break others:

[image]

Comment: Without `mtpro2`, the space does not manifest.  However, it does show, when, instead of `mtpro2`, one uses `newtxmath`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes You've given me some very bad news. :-( I have the whole book with `mtpro2` because I like fonts.

Comment: The problem can also be highlighted with `\ooalign{$d\bar{p}$\cr$dp$}`

Comment: If the problem is universal with `\bar` in that font, you could always do `\let\svbar\bar\renewcommand\bar{\mkern-1mu\svbar}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I tried your code in the comment. But it gives me two p's on top of each other. I would not like to change all the bars, at least for the moment, 334 pages. :-(

Comment: Yes, if the two superimposed `p`'s are "thick", that means the kerning is different between the two cases.  If the superimposed p's look like one, then the kerning is correct.

Comment: I removed some offtopic comments. (the conversation seemed to be finished anyway). Thanks.

Comment: @Sebastiano -- The present "title" of thiis question doesn't make much sense to me.  Would you be willing to change it to the following:  Is the space after the differential d operator canonical when using a Times font?

Comment: @barbarabeeton You know very well I'm scarce in English :-)...of course you can change it. :-)

Answer (score 19):

A proposal to renew the command of `\bar` as follows:

```
\let\svbar\bar
\renewcommand\bar[1]{%
  #1\ThisStyle{\setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}\kern-\wd0}\svbar{\,\phantom{#1}}\!}
```

This will guarantee proper kerning of the letter, as it is set first thing without the `\bar`.  Then, I kern backward across the letter, and apply the `\bar` to a variant of the letter's `\phantom`.  In this case, the variant is a shifted `\phantom`, which is then unshifted following the `\bar`, so as not to introduce any stray space.

Therefore, if there are residual kerning issues, they will be with the placement of the superimposed bar, relative to the underlying properly kerned letter.

The MWE uses the `\ooalign` test given in the question to judge the quality of the `\bar` macro, using letter boldness as an indicator for bad kerning.  As you can see, there are no thick/boldened letters signifying a kern mismatch.  Therefore, with this approach, one must merely judge if the placement of the bar relative to the letter is suitable or not.

While all examples are shown relative to the letter "d", the method, in fact, will perform similarly, regardless of the preceding letter.

EDITED to work across math styles.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}%instead of \usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\let\svbar\bar
\renewcommand\bar[1]{%
  #1\ThisStyle{\setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}\kern-\wd0}\svbar{\,\phantom{#1}}\!}
\newcommand\testkern[2][]{%
  \ooalign{$#1 d\bar{#2}$\cr$#1 d#2$}}
\textwidth 1in
\begin{document}
\noindent\testkern{a} \testkern{b} \testkern{c} \testkern{d}
\testkern{e} \testkern{f} \testkern{g} \testkern{h} \testkern{i}
\testkern{j} \testkern{k} \testkern{l} \testkern{m} \testkern{n}
\testkern{o} \testkern{p} \testkern{q} \testkern{r} \testkern{s}
\testkern{t} \testkern{u} \testkern{v} \testkern{w} \testkern{x}
\testkern{y} \testkern{z}

\noindent\testkern[\scriptstyle]{a} \testkern[\scriptstyle]{b} 
\testkern[\scriptstyle]{c} \testkern[\scriptstyle]{d}
\testkern[\scriptstyle]{e} \testkern[\scriptstyle]{f} 
\testkern[\scriptstyle]{g} \testkern[\scriptstyle]{h} 
\testkern[\scriptstyle]{i} \testkern[\scriptstyle]{j} 
\testkern[\scriptstyle]{k} \testkern[\scriptstyle]{l} 
\testkern[\scriptstyle]{m} \testkern[\scriptstyle]{n}
\testkern[\scriptstyle]{o} \testkern[\scriptstyle]{p} 
\testkern[\scriptstyle]{q} \testkern[\scriptstyle]{r} 
\testkern[\scriptstyle]{s} \testkern[\scriptstyle]{t} 
\testkern[\scriptstyle]{u} \testkern[\scriptstyle]{v} 
\testkern[\scriptstyle]{w} \testkern[\scriptstyle]{x}
\testkern[\scriptstyle]{y} \testkern[\scriptstyle]{z}

\noindent$2 d\bar{p}^2\ne2d p^2$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My always thanks from my first question I asked two and a half years ago :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano It has been my pleasure to assist you.

Comment: Steven I can't get a green check mark. I'm sorry. The two answers are both beautiful.

Comment: @Sebastiano No problem.  Sometimes, a question without a checkmark brings more eyes, from those thinking it is still unanswered.

Comment: I really appreciate the answers. When I can't choose, they are rare for me, it's because I can't penalize one user over another.

Answer (score 15):

If I compile

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}

$d\bar{p}$

$dp$

\showoutput

\end{document}
```

I get, for the two formulas

```
....\mathon
....\LMP1/mtt/m/it/12 d
....\kern1.43999
....\vbox(7.88399+2.568)x7.98
.....\hbox(7.88399+0.0)x0.0, shifted 3.312
......\LMP2/mtt/m/n/12 N
.....\kern-5.484
.....\hbox(5.484+2.568)x7.98
......\LMP1/mtt/m/it/12 p
....\mathoff
```

```
....\mathon
....\LMP1/mtt/m/it/12 d
....\kern1.43999
....\kern-2.40001
....\LMP1/mtt/m/it/12 p
....\kern0.48
....\mathoff
```

After removing the call to `mtpro2`, I get

```
....\mathon
....\OML/cmm/m/it/12 d
....\vbox(6.77774+2.33331)x5.89717
.....\hbox(6.77774+0.0)x0.0, shifted 0.99028
......\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 ^^V
.....\kern-5.16667
.....\hbox(5.16667+2.33331)x5.89717
......\OML/cmm/m/it/12 p
....\mathoff
```

```
....\mathon
....\OML/cmm/m/it/12 d
....\OML/cmm/m/it/12 p
....\mathoff
```

The obvious difference is that `d` in the font `\LMP1/mtt/m/it/12` (pointing to `mt2mit at 12pt`) has an italic correction, which isn't present in the `\OML/cmm/m/it/12` font (pointing to `cmsy10 at 12pt`).

Indeed, if I do `tftopl mt2mit`, I get

```
(CHARACTER C d
   (CHARWD R 0.551)
   (CHARHT R 0.717)
   (CHARIC R 0.12)
   (COMMENT
      (KRN O 0 R -0.06)
      [...]
      (KRN C p R -0.2)
      [...]
      (KRN C t R -0.04)
      [...]
      (KRN O 263 R -0.02)
      )
   )
```

and with `tftopl cmsy10` I get

```
(CHARACTER O 100
   (CHARWD R 0.611113)
   (CHARHT R 0.694445)
   )
```

As you can see, there is also a kerning pair with `p` or `t`, which moves in the character when there is no accent, but this is not possible when the next item is an Acc atom.

You can manually compute the appropriate kerning.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\newcommand{\dwithbar}[1]{%
  d\computedaccentkern{#1}\bar{#1}%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\computedaccentkern}[1]{%
  \mathpalette\computedaccentkern@{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\computedaccentkern@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1d#2$}
  \sbox\tw@{$\m@th#1d{\kern0pt#2}$}%
  \kern\dimexpr\wd\z@-\wd\tw@\relax
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

$d\bar{p}$ $\scriptstyle d\bar{p}$

$\dwithbar{p}$ $\scriptstyle \dwithbar{p}$

$dp$ $\scriptstyle dp$

$d\bar{t}$ $\scriptstyle d\bar{t}$

$\dwithbar{t}$ $\scriptstyle \dwithbar{t}$

$dt$ $\scriptstyle dt$

\end{document}
```

You can define similarly for other accents, say `\dot`:

```latex
\newcommand{\dwithdot}[1]{%
  d\computedaccentkern{#1}\dot{#1}%
}
```

or a generic

```latex
\newcommand{\dwithacc}[2]{%
  d\computedaccentkern{#2}#1{#2}%
}
```

to be called like `\dwithacc\bar{p}` or `\dwithacc\dot{p}`.

[image]

Comment: Shocking :-) I dare say amazed. I don't understand almost anything (`\mathon...\mathoff `:-) where they come from, `CHARACTER` etc...) but I can imagine that it's a problem with encoding the different incompatible fonts that I'm using.

Comment: @Sebastiano The first part is the analysis of what TeX internally does with the input, in terms of boxes and glue. Then I looked at the metrics for the fonts, finding the correspondence with what we saw in the boxes and glue representation.

Comment: Do i understand your solution correctly that it specifically addresses kerns following the letter "d", or is it universal for any letter combinations?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes It's specifically for d, but could be modified quite easily for other pairs.

Comment: @egreg Doesn't know who to vote for the two questions to. If I don't, it's because they're both beautiful.

Comment: I'm sorry, but in your beautiful answer I didn't thank you. I'm doing it now.

Answer (score 3):

This is more of a comment, but requires an example.

The problem described does not occur with Computer Modern, and the reason is the difference in the metrics in the `.tfm` file: the "d" in the alphabet used for math does not have an italic correction.  This is by design, since "d" is most often used by Knuth for the differential operator; if he uses it as a variable, he would add a thin space following the "d" if needed.

Here is the example used in the question, set with Computer Modern.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
The differential $d$ as set using Computer Modern: \qquad
$d\bar{p}$ and $dt$.
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

In short, the space that is inserted (differently with and without diacritics on the letter following the "d") is the result of metrics for the "d" not being defined in the same manner used in Computer Modern.  (This is not a problem when an upright "d" is used for the differential function.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your precious answer and contribute.

Answer (score 1):

This could be an intermediate solution, without macro, using  `diffcoeff` package (I remember that `derivative` package - see pag. 29 - does not include the differential symbol as shown in this image) with the option `ISO` to have upright differential symbol.

[image]

In this case it is possible to observe that a bit of horizontal spacing has decreased.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{derivative}
\usepackage[ISO]{diffcoeff}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 \frac{d\bar{p}}{dt}, \quad 
  \diff{\bar{p}}{t} \, 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

For those who would like to compile the code and they haven't installed `\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}` to replace it with `\usepackage{newtxmath}`. The only difference is the length of the `\bar` above the letter.