# Mathematics font: What font is this?

Tags: fonts

What font is seen in the picture? (the book is Fundamentals of Complex Analysis by Saff and Snider.): [image]

Comment: Have you tried any of the things mentioned in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/?

Comment: Yes but most of what I install to find fonts in documents never works due to the device I use.

Comment: I think this kind of fonts is used by "Cambridge university press" but I'm not sure, please affirm that if it's correct!

Comment: Yes you are correct. Many university presses use this font and Springer does as well. I thought it might be a common font but I have had a really difficult time finding it... and every book I own is in this font!

Comment: Typical Times font. The recommended one in LaTeX nowadays is `newtx`: https://ctan.org/pkg/newtx.

Comment: @ivankokan - The `newtxmath` math font package is definitely an improvement over the older `txfonts` and `mathptmx` packages. I don't think, though, that the `newtxmath` package can be said to be "better" than the `mtpro2` package -- other than the fact that `newtxmath` is free of charge whereas the `mtpro2` package is commercial and non-free (though not particularly expensive either).

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For my humble opinion it is

```
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
```

Here a screenshot taken from the documentation of [`newtx`](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/fonts/newtx/doc/newtxdoc.pdf) pag. 17:

[image]

And here's a reproduction of the first long equation in the screenshot you posted:

[image]

This is the link to install the font [mtpro2](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mtp2lite) v. [lite](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/mtp2lite.zip) (hence it is not complete).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext} % Times Roman clone text font (not crucial)
\usepackage[zswash,lite]{mtpro2} % math font package
\begin{document}
\[
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-3ix}}{2(x^2+4)}dx+0
   =-2\pi i \lim_{z\to-2i}(z+2i)f_2(z)
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I got an error message: "...mtpro... not found"

Comment: @user143 Yes of course...you must download before the package of the fonts and install them.

Comment: Haha. Thank you!

Comment: `mtpro2` is available here: https://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html

Comment: @RichardSullivan Yes, naturally, I know this package....but you should pay to have the complete list fonts.

Comment: You chose a very good excerpt from the OP's screenshot -- one that includes both `\int` and `\infty` -- to demonstrate that the math font is not just any old Times Roman (TR) clone but, specifically, `mtpro2`. Virtually all other TR math fonts I'm familiar with draw the infinity symbol with a constant stroke width; `mtpro` is almost unique in varying the stroke width of this symbol.

Comment: @Mico Sometimes the wheel of fortune turns for me too...but I'd like another wheel of serenity to turn :-( I remembered something in the documentation since I often use it for my book...

Comment: @Mico Thank youuuuu very much for to have improved my answer. 

Comment: @Sebastiano - You're most welcome. :-)

Comment: +1 You have to look carefully to find what is the character font. How did you do ?

Comment: @AndréC  with the mask...to keep my smile out of view. If you look at my profile there are a lot of questions about mtpro2 which is a package I really like. For me it's the favorite. I immediately recognized the fonts by the integral symbol.

Comment: It is true that it is a very pretty typeface. I didn't see anything from `mtpro` on your profile, I didn't have to look where I should (as usual)

Comment: @AndréC Select the tag mtpro.

Comment: Ah yes, 31 results!

Comment: Hmmm.  Hadn't noticed this before about `mtpro2` -- there really shouldn't be any space between "d" and "x". They're not multiplying one another; the "d" is the differential operator.  Otherwise it *is* a very nice font.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Very kind Barbara, of course the "d" it is the differential operator but the space between "d" and "x" it is very bit. You can see my old question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483128/is-it-canonical-bit-space. For my opinion it is the very very very nice font.

Comment: @Sebastiano -- I have added a new answer to your old question explaining that the extra space is the result of a different approach to metrics between Computer Modern and other fonts used for math variables.

Answer (score 8):

Here's your font according to @ivankokan `\usepackage{newtxtext}`and `\usepackege{newtxmath}`

```
\documentclass{article} 
    \usepackage{newtxtext}
    \usepackage{newtxmath}  
   \begin{document}
However, the combination \[\int_{-\rho}^{\rho} f_2(x)dx+\int_{C_\rho^-}f_2(z)dz\] equals \textit{minus} $2\pi \mathrm{Res}(f_2 ;-2i)$, because$\cdots$ 
   \end{document}
```

And here's your text! good luck!
[image]

Comment: +1. A clue that `newtxmath` was *not* used in the production of the Saff & Snider textbook is that the `+` symbol produced by `newtxmath` uses fairly short and thick strokes and that the symbol's vertical stroke does not protrude below the baseline. In contrast, the `+` symbol shown in the OP's screenshot employs a thinner as well as longer strokes, with the vertical stroke clearly protruding below the baseline. Of course, these observations do not imply that `newtxmath` isn't a fine package. Quite to the contrary! It just means that `newtxmath` wasn't used in the textbook.