# Spacing of italic differential d in mtpro2

Tags: mtpro, italic-correction, font-metrics

Differential quantities with the `mtpro2` font package don't typeset correctly (I think) because of the italic correction on the `d` character.

Using this post

[Math letter's italic correction](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16433/math-letters-italic-correction/71065#71065)

I decided to try and remove the italic correction. While this works for some differentials, it doesn't work for all of them. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mtpro2}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand*\ric[1]{\vphantom{#1}\smash{#1_{}\kern-\scriptspace}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{matrix}
 \text{with italic correction} &dx & d\tau \\
 \text{without italic correction} &\ric{d}x & \ric{d}\tau
\end{matrix}
\]
\[
\begin{matrix}
 \text{with italic correction} &df & dj \\
 \text{without italic correction} &\ric{d}f & \ric{d}j
\end{matrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

and output
[image: tex output]

Clearly `d\tau` and `dx` benefit enormously from having the italic correction removed whereas `df` and `dj` suffer and get moved too far apart. The discussion in

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/557217/95517

seems to suggest that this is because `mtpro2` defines the font metrics for `d` differently from Computer Modern, which treats `d` primarily as a differential operator. How can I get the spacing for `d` to be that of a differential operator?

Comment: Anyway, the differential should be typed in upshape – it is not a variable.

Comment: @Bernard That's not true. Perhaps *you* prefer it upright, but many people have different opinions.

Comment: @egreg: I think using italic like a variable is very confusing. It is an operator, after all.

Comment: @Bernard It is *not* an operator in this case (or not necessarily interpreted as an operator, if you wish). To me the whole “dx” is a variable.

Comment: For me, it is an infinitesimal increment of the variable x. And df is the linear map that is the best linear approximation of the function f in  a neighbourhood of a point x.

Comment: TeX adds both the italic correction *and* the kern for the pair of characters if they come from the same font; there is no kern defined between “d” and ”tau”.  I think it was a bad choice to define an italic correction for d.

Comment: @Bernard For me, “infinitesimal increment” is nonsense.

Comment: @egreg Since you think the italic correction for "d" is a bad idea, what do you think is a good workaround that doesn't mess up the spacing for "df"? Is the only solution editing the tfm file?